# What is the probability of getting 2 green balls out of 4 draws in a finite sample space through method of counting?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am not understanding why trying to find the probability through counting isn't working for the following example:

**Example**: You have an urn with 3 Red balls and 3 Blue balls. If you draw 4 balls out of the urn, what is the probability of getting exactly 2 Red balls?

So the obvious solution is P(2 Red balls) = 3/6 * 2/5 * 3/4 * 2/3 = 0.1

However if I try to find P(2 Red balls) by counting, I get a different answer:
Out of 4 draws, you can get the following combinations:

- 3 Red, 1 Blue: C(4 balls, 3 Red) = 4 total combinations
- 2 Red, 2 Blue: C(4 balls, 2 Red) = 6 total combinations
- 1 Red, 3 Blue: C(4 balls, 1 Red) = 4 total combinations

So if I divide the total number of outcome combinations of having exactly 2 Red balls from 4 draws against the total number of outcome combinations from 4 draws, I get: P(2 Red balls) = 6/14 = 0.428 which is not 0.1.

What is wrong with my method of counting?

Comment: Your “obvious solution” is flawed

Comment: The first probability of $0.1$ you calculated is the probability that the first 2 balls drawn are red and the last two balls drawn are blue which doesn't account that you can pick a red ball in any of the 4 draws.

Comment: Concerning the counting solution, I get $3-9-3$

Comment: Your amounts of $4,6,4$ respectively are also flawed.  You counted just the orders in which the balls could come out but not *which* balls they happened to be.  Compare this to the problem where you have a billion red balls and one blue ball and you draw two balls.  By your method of counting, you have $1$ possibility for having drawn two red balls, and $2$ possibilities for having drawn a red and a blue, leading you to incorrectly believe the probability of drawing a blue among two balls from this urn containing a billion red balls and only one blue to be $\dfrac{2}{3}$... absurd

Comment: To use counting techniques you should have been keeping track of *which* balls they were, having temporarily made the assumption that the balls are in fact distinctly labeled (*even if in reality they aren't*).  The order in which they were pulled may be kept track of or ignored depending on your preference *so long as you are consistent about the choice*, having both numerator *and* denominator using the same choice about order mattering or not mattering.  Either choice will lead to the same final answer after simplifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{6}{4}=15$ ways to draw 4 balls out of the urn with 6 balls.

There are $\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} = 9$ ways to draw two of the three red balls and two out of the three blue balls.

So the correct answer is $\frac{9}{15}=\frac{3}{5}$.

Your "obvious method" assumes you draw RRBB (or BBRR) in that fixed order. So you count too few.

Comment: Thanks! that cleared a lot of things up.